# getImageData on canvas after translation and rotation

Tags: javascript, rotation, html5-canvas, getimagedata

I'm trying to extract a part of an image through the getImageData function for canvas.

The difficulty is that my part is rotated. My goal is to extract for example the rectangle on the image : [image]

To draw the rectangle below, I use a translation and a rotation, but these functions don't work when we use getImageData.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  drawRect();
}
img.src = "https://dummyimage.com/300x150/5873f0/ffffff.jpg";


function drawRect() {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(75, 100);
  ctx.rotate(20 * Math.PI / 180)
  // imgData = ctx.getImageData(-50, -25, 100, 50);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.strokeRect(-50, -25, 100, 50);
  ctx.restore()
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

This is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplante/6vLoa8st) I use. Thanks!

Comment: What is cWidth and cHeight in your fiddle?

Comment: Sorry I put the wrong Fiddle. I edited!

Comment: When you remove the commented out section and run the image code in your fiddle, you get the following in console *Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.* Have you looked into [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image) yet?